# Definition of manifold which are subset of euclidean space

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

According to Guillemin and Pollack "X(which is a subset of R^n)is a  k-dimensional manifold  if it is locally diffeomorphic to Rk , meaning that each point 
 x possesses a neighborhood  V  in X which is diffeomorphie to an open set
 U of R^k".
My question is why does this definition not contradicting the fact the diffeomorphism is only possible between manifold of same dimension?

Comment: The manifold is $k$-dimensional and $\Bbb R^k$ is $k$-dimensional.  What's the problem?

Comment: but its a subset of R^n

Comment: So?  A line is $1$-dimensional.  Does that mean that if we embed the line in $\Bbb R^3$ that it suddenly becomes $3$-dimensional?

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion is around the $k$ vs. $n$. If so, I think the point is that the dimension of a manifold is **not** the dimension of the Euclidean space of which it is a subset (if it even is a subset of some Euclidean space).

For example, consider the Klein bottle $K$. $K$ can be viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$, but is $2$-dimensional, and cannot be viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (let alone $\mathbb{R}^2$). The number $4$ (= dimension of smallest Euclidean space into which $K$ embeds) tells you something about the manifold $K$, but it is *not* the dimension.

Put another way: If I have $K$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$, then it is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$; but this in no way implies that $\mathbb{R}^4$ is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.